# A notation that specifies that modular arithmetic has been used

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, determinant

[image: $Gallian$]
Usually when we write $\det A = 1$, it is implied that usual arithmetic on the set of real numbers has been adopted. Here we have used modulo 5 arithmetic. Shouldn't we use some other notation to indicate that when writing the value of the determinant?

Comment: We should write $\det(A)\equiv 1 \bmod 5$. But this it, what they want to say. We can write equations of matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$. Then $\det(A)=1$ is an equation in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One thing I wanted to ask. Do $a mod n = b$ and $a ≡ b (mod n)$ have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, $-4\bmod 5=1$ should be read as $-4\equiv 1\bmod 5$.

Comment: This depends on the spacing: $\;a\bmod n$ denotes  the value of the remainder in the division of $a$ by $n$. It is an integer. On the other hand $\; a\equiv b\mod n$ or $\;a\equiv b\pmod n$ denotes the *congruence relation* between $a$ and $b$.($a$ and $b$ have the same remainder).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I don't agree: $a\bmod n$ is a function from $\mathbf Z$ to  $\mathbf Z$, implemented in computer algebra software. Note that $a\bmod n$ is not typed the same a $a\mod n$.

Comment: $a$ $mod$ $n$ is a non-negative integer less than $n$ whereas in the other one $b$ can be greater than $n$ or even negative, yes?

Comment: @Bernard Are you implying that you use two different denotations for $\, a\bmod n$ depending on how much whitespace surrounds the operator? Such an extreme abuse of notation would surely cause great confusion for beginners.

Comment: I do use both spacings according to the context. There are two different LaTeX commands for that. I think it suffices to explain beginners.

Comment: @HritRoy: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Hrit Yes, technically the equalities should be congruences, and the hypothesis that all arithmetic is modulo $5$ should *precede* its invocation. Unfortunately there is widespread abuse of congruence notation (which is usually not problematic at higher levels, but may prove particularly perplexing to beginners).

Comment: @Bernard With $\TeX$ one can typeset all sorts of nonsense, so that doesn't imply much.

Comment: But $a\bmod n$  is a very useful notation!